# JList gets wrong dimensions with custom ListCellRenderer

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I've got a `JList<MyObj>`, for which I created a custom `ListCellRenderer<MyObj>`. This list is contained in a `JScrollPane`.

To avoid resizing the frame at *runtime*, I expect the scroll pane to always have the appropriate size to display `VISIBLE_ITEMS` of my elements, whether the list starts out empty, or populated. The following is the *setup* code for the list.

```
model   = new DefaultListModel<>();
list    = new JList<>(model);

list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
list.setVisibleRowCount(VISIBLE_ITEMS);
list.setCellRenderer(new MyItem());
    /* ... */
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(list);
panel.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

`MyItem` is defined as follows.

```
/**
 * A component that displays a single item.
 */
private static final class MyItem extends JPanel
        implements ListCellRenderer<MyObj> {
    // ...

    private final JLabel label;
    private final JTextArea text;

    MyItem() {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        label   = new JLabel(PLACEHOLDER);
        text    = new JTextArea(PLACEHOLDER, 3, CHARS_PER_ROW);

        label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEADING);
        text.setEditable(false);
        text.setLineWrap(true);
        text.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        text.setMargin(new Insets(5, 10, 5, 5));

        super.add(text, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        super.add(label, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent
            (JList<? extends MyObj> list, MyObj value, int index,
            boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        setLabel(value.getArg1());
        text.setText(value.getArg2());
        return this;
    }

    private void setLabel(String arg) {
        label.setText(new StringBuilder(35 + arg.length())
            .append("<html><b><u>").append(arg)
            .append("</u></b></html>").toString());
    }
}
```

When the list starts out empty, its preferred size seems to be enough for `VISIBLE_ITEMS` rows of regular strings. However, if I hardcode some `MyObj` to initialize the list, it has the right dimensions.

Is this a problem with my cell renderer, or is this the expected behaviour of `JList`, in general?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you want to call JList's `setPrototypeCellValue(...)` method to allow the JList to set its fixed cell width and height.  Please have a look at the [JList API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) for more details on this as well as an example.

Comment: That seems to have solved the issue. I must have overlooked the documentation. Funny, that I took the cell renderer example from there, and missed this, which comes immediately after.

Comment: @afsantos: that's what stackoverflow is for. Glad this helped.